# Chrome does not run jQuery after XAMPP installed

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, xampp

I work on a website and I added some jQuery to it. Things were going well I could open the site from local drive with Chrome and the site was running. I use google's jQuery link on the site.

After I installed XAMPP Chrome stopped load and run jQuery.

I got this error message on the console when it tried to load my xyz.js:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

First I load jquery.min.js from google and after that my own xyz.js

```
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async src="js/xyz.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Website is reached from:

> file:///Path To/index.html

I did not even installed apach or anything with XAMPP I just installed and run XAMPP itself. So I uninstalled XAMPP but the problem remained unsolved.

The code runs on Edge perfectly but I prefer chrome instead.

How can I solve this issue with Chrome and jQuery?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: I think the problem may lie in async loading of scripts. Can you try to insert scripts without `async` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `async` property from the `<script>` tag including jQuery in the page.

jQuery *has* to be loaded before any script that relies on it, otherwise you'll see your '$ is undefined' error due to the `xyz.js` file attempting to use the library before it's available in the page. Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async src="js/xyz.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thx for the quick answer. Although I do not understand what was the problem since the code was untouched before and after XAMPP installation.

Comment: Glad to help. It may have been working by sheer luck - if the async call to jquery.js loaded before xyz.js, then you'd have no problems. At least this method guarantees that will always happen.